# Declare all the parameters set for a method, even when they are not used - performance issue

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have always considered it good practice to declare all method parameters even when they are not used.

For example, in the change event of a textfield:

```
change ( this, newValue, oldValue, eOpts ) //eOpts is not used in the concrete case
```

My doubts:

Declare all the parameters of a method even when part of them are not used, is it really a good practice?

Does this practice have any negative consequences (with relevance) on performance?

Comment: Good practice? IMO no, `eOpts` is always typically useless. For performance it will make no difference, they will be passed whether or not you declare them in the function signature.

Comment: Thanks Evan. I've tried to figure out if this practice has any effect on memory management in javascript.
Default function parameters allow formal parameters to be initialized with default values if no value or undefined is passed.
Apparently, declaring default parameters that are not used does not have negative effect (as far as I can see from the readings) in memory management;
When declaring the function, Javascript will automatically allocate the memory for the function itself.
However, in our case,  if the default  parameter is not being used it is not there to do anything. Right?

Comment: I particularly liked the following article: https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-memory-management-how-to-handle-4-common-memory-leaks-3f28b94cfbec

Comment: Sorry Evan for asking for more clarification. If I just declare, for example, change (btn, newValue) EXT JS and javascript will always pass change (btn, newValue, oldValue, eOpts)?

Comment: Yes, because it doesn't matter what you receive, it still passes the values regardless. Think the `arguments` collection.